# docker exec with find -exec option (find: missing argument to `-exec')

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run docker command on Windows 10 Enterprise as Admin:

```
docker-compose exec --user magento2 web find /var/www/sample-data -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```

but I got the error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I was trying to escape by using '' or "":

`docker-compose exec --user magento2 web "find /var/www/sample-data -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;"`

but it throws anouther error

`rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"find /var/www/sample-data -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \\\\;\": sta
t find /var/www/sample-data -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \\;: no such file or directory"`

How I can resolve this issue? Normaly when I insert this command inside the container - everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sh instead:

```
docker-compose exec --user magento2 web sh -c 'find /var/www/sample-data -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;'
```